# Assigning classes to elements through CSS

Tags: html, css

I'd like to tell the browser to assign certain CSS classes to elements matching a particular selector. Can I do it with pure CSS and if yes, how?

Example: I want all the `h5` elements inside a div with id `sidebar` to have the class `ui-corners-all`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

No, that isn't possible with pure CSS.

Only with JavaScript:

```
// jQuery
$("h5").addClass("ui-corners-all");

// Pure JavaScript
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("h5");
for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++)
{
  var el = elements[i];      
  el.setAttribute( "class", el.getAttribute("class") + " ui-corners-all" );
}
```

Comment: Would this be a weird way to apply bootstrap classes? I'm interested in doing this so that I can keep track of all the css being applied to an element but I also want to end up removing bootstrap/combining it with the overrides under my class names with something like unCSS and I'm not sure if it will cause problems with that or other things.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to assign this value to those elements in pure CSS.

You would need to do:

```css
#sidebar h5
{

}
```

Then copy all styles from `ui-corners-all` class into this.

Or alternatively, change your `ui-corners-all` CSS to:

```css
.ui-corners-all, #sidebar h5
{    

}
```

Comment: Updated my answer, as there is no way of assigning these in pure css, so ive provided an alternative

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. You can however use Javascript ([*jQuery*](http://jquery.com/) recommended) to achieve this effect.

Comment: I think he's already using jQuery and jQuery UI (`ui-corners-all`) ;)